# Python's weird behavior about rounding

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, rounding-error

The question is simple, why this:

```
>>> (2**32-1)**2 - 4.0**2 - (2**32-1)**2
0.0
>>> (2**32-1)**2 - (2**32-1)**2 - 4.0**2
-16.0
```

I know it has to be something about float roundoff error but I need a formal explanation and How can we avoid this such of error?

P/s: Im using python 2.7.3, MacOSX, 64bits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python int types can outrun your platform word size with ease, but floating point values are tied to the hardware. Don't mix long int and floating point values.

In your first sample, the size of the first integer number far outstrips the maxim precision of floating point numbers.

On a 64bit Mac, the maximum number of decimal digits that a float can represent is 15:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.dig
15
```

but your integers use 20 digits. To match the exponent the 16.0 float has to be truncated to 15 significant digits and that means it is basically rounded to 0.

If you **have** to use floating point arithmetic with long integers, use the `decimal.Decimal()` type, it is not limited by hardware:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> (2**32-1)**2 - decimal.Decimal('4.0') ** 2 - (2**32-1)**2
Decimal('-16.00')
```

Comment: Thank you, Martijn. It makes sense to me but Why does python have to do that inconvenient way? Is it about performance?

Comment: @vutran: hardware-assisted FP has been the norm in computing for a few decades now; yes, using the floating point support is a lot faster.

Comment: @vutran Also, very few, if any, real-world measurements are accurate to more than 53 bits. That makes hardware floating point both efficient and accurate enough for much of scientific and engineering programming.